# How to use a portion of existing dataset in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use only first 10% of each class of CIFAR10 dataset in tensorflow resnet example [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet).

In this case, what is the most simple way to change? I don't exactly understand the data class in Tensorflow...

Answer (score 1):

Filtering the dataset *exactly* 10% per class can be a bit hairy, but if your goal is just to *try* ResNet on a smaller dataset, the simplest way is to [`skip`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset#skip) 90% of the dataset, which will reduce each class *approximately* to 10%. If this is ok for you, simply add `skip` [after the `shuffle` call](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/resnet/cifar10_main.py#L161):

```
...
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=_SHUFFLE_BUFFER)
dataset = dataset.skip(54000)
...
```

.. which will cause the `dataset` to skip 90% of 60000 examples and return only 6000.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though it is not exactly what I want, it can be a good alternative. One question is, the above modification make it returns exactly 5000 training examples and 1000 test examples? or return only 6000 training examples?

Comment: In training time (e.g. when `is_training=True`), `get_filenames` returns only training data files, so test is not used at all. The call that I refer to in my answer is also under `is_training=True` condition

Comment: Okay, I understood. Thanks.